# Zend Gdata include path issue

Tags: php, zend

I'm having some trouble with a Zend Gdata install. I copied the files into the `/usr/lib/php` folder and ran a script that said all was working. However, when I go to run any demo script I get the following error:

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Loader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/lib/php/ZendGdata/demos/Zend/Gdata/Spreadsheet-ClientLogin.php on line 26

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Loader.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php') in /usr/lib/php/ZendGdata/demos/Zend/Gdata/Spreadsheet-ClientLogin.php on line 26
```

The obvious solution is the include_path. However, that's where things get weird. Here's a screenshot from a phpinfo() pull of current status:

[image: Screenshot of phpinfo()]

As you can see from the error message above, PHP is still looking for the default path.  I've searched the machine (I'm using a Mac dev environment) for any system files called `php.ini` and can only find the one I'm working on.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.